# Django - Data from Views to HTML

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Hello I am learning Django and I cannot pass data from model to view. I am trying to make a simple blog for learning purpose, but always when i render view, variable is present if i do an if condition but when i am trying to access that variable - it writes Did you forget to register or load this tag error..

html:

```
{% if posts %}
    {% posts %}
{% else %}
    without posts
{% endif %}
```

models.py:

```
STATUS = (
    (0,"Draft"),
    (1,"Publish")
)


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    img = models.ImageField()
    description = models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    wide_img = models.ImageField()
    hide_img = models.ImageField()
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete= models.CASCADE)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
from blog.models import Post

def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('?')[:3]
    context = {
        "posts": "jaj",
    }
    template_name="index.html"
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are displayed using double braces, not braces + % (which is for templatetags). IOW you want:

```
{% if posts %}
  {{ posts }}
{% else %}
   without posts
{% endif %}
```

The error message could have been a hint, as it suggests it doesn't recognize `{% posts %}` as a known templatetag.